# Rewrite url to show .php extension?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

so I'm trying to rewrite a url to display a .php extension.

I have the following structure

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)+mp3+download.php?$ index.php?search=$1 [L]
```

but it's not working with download.php as the extension, if I change it to .html and change the +'s to -'s it works though.

Does anyone see an issue with the way I'm doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `+` since that is special regex symbol:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*?)\+mp3\+download\.php$ index.php?search=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Manages to fix it by changing the rewrite to the following

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)\+mp3\+download.(.*)?$ index.php?search=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Guess so, thank you for your response though I appreciate it.